# How to detect the reason of app crash?

Tags: c++, macos, crash-reports

I have little bit modified the PostgreSQL odbc driver, built in on Mac OS X, then run the iODBC Administrator, it crashed with dump:

```
Process:               iODBC Administrator64 [2817]
Path:                  /Applications/iODBC/iODBC Administrator64.app/Contents/MacOS/iODBC Administrator64
Identifier:            org.iodbc.iODBCAdministrator64
Version:               iODBC Administrator64 version 3.52.12 (3.52.12)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           iODBC Administrator64 [2817]

OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.13.3 (17D102)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        EBAEDCCA-DFB6-7D4B-77DE-98E6D56BD279


Time Awake Since Boot: 6000 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000068
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Signal:    Segmentation fault: 11
Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
Terminating Process:   exc handler [0]

VM Regions Near 0x68:
--> 
    __TEXT                 0000000104715000-0000000104719000 [   16K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /Applications/iODBC/iODBC Administrator64.app/Contents/MacOS/iODBC Administrator64

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff5b869ea9 flockfile + 18
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff5b87292d vfprintf + 24
2   pgodbc.so                       0x000000010a0aa248 mylog + 408
3   pgodbc.so                       0x000000010a057e3a PGAPI_AllocEnv + 42
4   pgodbc.so                       0x000000010a0a108c SQLAllocHandle + 76
5   org.iodbc.core                  0x0000000104746079 _iodbcdm_driverload + 1113
6   org.iodbc.core                  0x0000000104748345 SQLDriverConnect_Internal +
```

1. How to understand what is the reason of crash?
2. Is it possible to use try {} catch(...) {} for this kind of exceptions on Mac OS X? will it catch them?

Comment: Use your debugger to analyze the crash dump.

Comment: "Termination Signal:    Segmentation fault: 11" says segfault. For more information how your program got taken down by a segfault you'll probably have to provide a [mcve]. That's going to be hard, and to be honest I bet once you get half way to a MCVE you'll have it figured out yourself. I'd start by looking at your logger. Only think I can think of off the top that should blow up `flockfile` is a bad file handle.

Comment: Is there way to understand what is this text, may be it can help to understand the reason: VM Regions Near 0x68: __TEXT                 0000000104715000-0000000104719000

Comment: Check the stack last called function when your app crashed through a debugger

Comment: Ok, thnx, is it possible to use try {} catch(...) {} for this kind of exceptions?

Comment: have you find solution??? I have same issue. Due to this app rejected by Apple Store.

Comment: Yes, I have found. As I remember it was bad pointer in the function mylog.